# Drawing a Dragons curve in Python

Tags: python, fractals

I am trying to work out how to draw the dragons curve,  with pythons turtle using the An L-System or Lindenmayer system. I no the code is something like

the Dragon curve; initial state = ‘F’, replacement rule – replace ‘F’ with ‘F+F-F’, number of replacements = 8, length = 5, angle = 60

But have no idea how to put that into code.

Answer (score 3):

First hit on Google for "dragons curve python":

http://www.pynokio.org/dragon.py.htm

You can probably modify that to work with your plotting program of choice. I'd try matplotlib.

Comment: unfortunately the link you posted is not working anymore?

Answer (score 3):

Draw the dragon curve using `turtle` module (suggested by [@John Fouhy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765048/drawing-a-dragons-curve-in-python/766310#766310)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import turtle
from functools import partial

nreplacements = 8
angle = 60
step = 5

# generate command
cmd = 'f'
for _ in range(nreplacements):
    cmd = cmd.replace('f', 'f+f-f')

# draw
t = turtle.Turtle()
i2c = {'f': partial(t.forward, step),
       '+': partial(t.left, angle),
       '-': partial(t.right, angle),
}
for c in cmd: i2c[c]()
```

Comment: Ha! If you manually compressed that it could almost fit in a tweet

Comment: import turtle;from functools import partial as p;n,a,s,c=(8,60,5,'f');
for _ in range(n):c=c.replace('f','f+f-f');t=turtle.Turtle();i={'f':p(t.forward,s),'+': p(t.left,a),'-':p(t.right,a)};
for b in c:i[b]()

Answer (score 0):

Well, presumably, you could start by defining:

```
def replace(s):
    return s.replace('F', 'F+F-F')
```

Then you can generate your sequence as:

```
code = 'F'
for i in range(8):
    code = replace(code)
```

I'm not familiar with `turtle` so I can't help you there.